# Push Local File From Electron to Server PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, electron

js and electron. I have a problem to push my local images file to my remote server. The server is using php. Here's my client side code :

```js
var documentList = [];

var stmtDoc = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_dokumen_pasien`");

while(stmtDoc.step()) {
  var rowDoc =  stmtDoc.getAsObject();
  var data = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/resources/" + rowDoc['id'] + "/" + rowDoc['doc_name']);

  var document = {
    "document_name" : rowDoc['doc_name'],
    "data" : data
  }

  documentList.push(document);
}
```

And after that I create an ajax post request to my remote server :

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://url/web_api.php?action=test_upload",
  type: 'POST',
  data : { "document_list": documentList },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

When I test it, in my developer tools console I've got this message :

```
internal/streams/BufferList.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

And the file is not sent to the server. Can anyone help me how can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a while I found the working solution for this problem is use base64 format to send it to the remote server :

```js
var documentList = [];

var stmtDoc = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_dokumen_pasien`");

while(stmtDoc.step()) {
  var rowDoc =  stmtDoc.getAsObject();
  var data = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/resources/" + rowDoc['id'] + "/" + rowDoc['doc_name']);
  var base64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');

  var document = {
    "document_name" : rowDoc['doc_name'],
    "data" : base64
  }

  documentList.push(document);
}
```

And I still finding the best approach instead of using base64, Thanks

Comment: `Buffer.from` expects a "string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object", so this throws a TypeError for me, when used on a readStream.